# Redis in Kubernetes - Connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, redis, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to deploy a **redis** pod to allow my staging app connecting to it (to avoid using Redis Managed Service in staging ENV).

I'm using **Google Cloud Platform** with **GKE**, so managed k8s cluster...

However, when I try to make a connection (from another redis pod only to test) I receive this message :

```
Could not connect to Redis at redis-cip.redis.svc.cluster.local:6379: Connection refused
```

The command that I use to make the test is this :

```
redis-cli -h redis-cip.redis.svc.cluster.local -p 6379
```

The URL is composed by :

- redis-cip: is the service ClusterIP that I use to allow connection to my redis POD
- redis : is the namespace where is hosted redis POD

Moreover,I use, as is already written in some question on StackOverflow, this redis configuration :

```
protected-mode no
maxmemory 32mb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

In attached the full k8s mapping :

ConfigMap :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: redis-configmap
  namespace: redis
data:
  redis.conf: |
    protected-mode no
    maxmemory 32mb
    maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

Redis Deploy :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: redis
spec:
  containers:
    - name: redis
      image: redis
      command:
        - redis-server
        - /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      env:
        - name: MASTER
          value: "true"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /redis-master-data
          name: data
        - mountPath: /usr/local/etc/redis/
          name: redis-configmap
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: {{ .Values.resources.requests.memory }}
          cpu: {{ .Values.resources.requests.cpu }}
        limits:
          memory: {{ .Values.resources.limits.memory }}
          cpu: {{ .Values.resources.limits.cpu }}
  volumes:
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: redis-configmap
      configMap:
        name: redis-configmap
```

ClusterIP Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-cip
  namespace: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
  type: ClusterIP
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the connection gets refused because there are no pods with label `app:redis` .
add labels to your pod that are identical to service `spec.selector`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: redis
  labels:
     app:redis
spec:
  containers:
    - name: redis
      image: redis
```

Comment: thank you, when you are focused on something that is not wrong is impossible to find the mistake...